# how to validate two fields in separate classes?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to validate two fields in separate `@ConfigurationProperties` classes. Properties in these classes are set by spring container. I cannot merge these two classes because of application design. How can achieve this validation?

I tried Observer pattern so that change in these classes is notified in some other class and then can be validated but Observer pattern is for *one-to-many* not *many-to-one*.

Trying to validate if `multipleQueuesEnabled` is set to false then `url` should not be null and `urls` should be null. And if `multipleQueuesEnabled` is set to true then `urls` should not be null and `url` should be null.

First Properties Class:-

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws.sqs")
@Validated
public class SqsProducerStarterProperties

    @NotNull
    private boolean multipleQueuesEnabled;


    public boolean isMultipleQueuesEnabled() {
        return multipleQueuesEnabled;
    }

    public void setMultipleQueuesEnabled(boolean multipleQueuesEnabled) {

        this.multipleQueuesEnabled = multipleQueuesEnabled;
    }

}
```

Second Properties Class:-

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws.sqs.fifo")
@Validated
public class SqsFifoStarterProperties {

    private Map<String, String> urls;

    private String url;

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getUrls() {
        return urls;
    }

    public void setUrls(Map<String, String> urls) {
        this.urls = urls;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
       this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts about how can I achieve validation in above scenario. Properties will be set by spring container so I do not have control over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I moved SqsFifoStarterProperties class as static class in SqsProducerStarterProperties class and then made a custom annotation to validate properties.